# Using windows command line to run python script with passing of url argument

Tags: windows, url, python-2.7, command-line-arguments, urllib

I am writing this Python program which extracts some information from a webpage and I am required to run it using the windows command line. But I could not even print the original html page as a string. I am using Python 2.7

Here is my Python script:

```
#sys.py
import sys
import urllib

url = sys.argv[1]
f = urllib.urlopen(url)
print f.read()
```

When I try to run it from windows command line with: C...>sys.py "www.marinetraffic.com/ais/shipdetails.aspx?mmsi=311389000"

Errors appear as follows:

```
Traceback(most recent call last):
File "C:\...\sys.py", line 14 in <module>
  f = urllib.urlopen(url)
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 87, in urlopen
  return opener.open(url)
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 208, in open
  return getattr(self, name)(url) 
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 463, in open_file
  return self.open_local_file(url)
File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib.py", line 87, in open_loca_file
  raise IOError(e.errno, e.strerror, e.filename)
IOError: [Errno 2] The system cannot find the path specified: 'www.marinetraffic.com\\ais\\shipdetails.aspx?mmsi=311389000'
```

There should not be any problem with the Python set up under the windows environment because I can still print out the sys.argv list as the arguments are passed in the command line.

Is it the problem with the 'urllib' library?

Is there any another way to run this using windows command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is the way you specify your url, it needs to have the http:// part at the start.

It works for me when I type

```
python sys.py http://www.google.com/
```

but fails with

```
python sys.py www.google.com
```

(Note that I am using linux with python 2.7 but I think it may be the same problem for you)